# Publishing Error: MSB4019 using dotnet publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using VS2017 (Version 15.7.3) and Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.7.02046
The project compiles and runs without problems from within the IDE.

I'm getting the following error when trying to publish my project on the command line:

```
>dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64

Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 15.7.179.6572 für .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webjobs.publish\2.0.0\build\webjobs.console.targets(24,3): error MSB4019: Das importierte Projekt "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" wurde nicht gefunden. Vergewissern Sie sich, dass der Pfad in der <Import>-Deklaration korrekt und die Datei auf dem Datenträger vorhanden ist. [C:\projectPath\MyProject\my_project.csproj]
```

I noticed that the path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications" does not exist on my machine, why is it looking there?

In English, it asks to check the  declaration:

```
Make sure that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct and that the file exists on the disk.
```

There is no  declaration anywhere in my project files.  What is this referring to?

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;win7-x86;ubuntu.16.04-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <SuppressDockerTargets>True</SuppressDockerTargets>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Mqtt\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Mqtt\**" />
    <None Remove="Mqtt\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="M2MqttDotnetCore" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Literate" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyProjectArchive\MyProjectArchive.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProjectSubscriptionService\MyProjectSubscriptionService.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="run.cmd">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Verbose Output (using -v d)

```
PROJECT_PATH>dotnet publish -v d -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 15.7.179.6572 für .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Buildvorgang wurde am 20.06.2018 10:17:21 gestartet.
     0>SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" wird aufgelöst...
       NdE: $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)="PROJECT_PATH\obj\" (vorheriger Wert: "obj\") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props (60,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS1" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS") unter NUGET.G.PROPS (13,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS2" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS1") unter NET.SDK.PROPS (15,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS3" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS2") unter NET.SDK.DEFAULT.PROPS (21,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS4" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS3") unter NET.SupTarFrameW.PROPS (17,9)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS4") unter NET.SDK.C#.PROPS (15,5)
       SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish" wird aufgelöst...
       NdE: $(OutputType)="Exe" (vorheriger Wert: "Library") unter PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj (3,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5") unter SDK_TARGETS_PATH (15,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP1" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (15,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP2" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP1") unter ms.net.defaultAssemblyInfo.targets (15,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP3" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP2") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.DefaultOutputPaths.targets (27,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP4" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP3") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (46,5)
       NdE: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Release\/**;obj\Release\/**" (vorheriger Wert: ";bin\Release\/**") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (166,5)
       NdE: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\" (vorheriger Wert: "obj\Release\") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (178,5)
       NdE: $(OutputPath)="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\" (vorheriger Wert: "bin\Release\") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (179,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP5" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP4") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets (15,5)
       NdE: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ubuntu.16.04-x64\" (vorheriger Wert: "obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets (150,5)
       NdE: $(OutputPath)="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ubuntu.16.04-x64\" (vorheriger Wert: "bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets (151,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP6" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP5") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.NuGetOfflineCache.targets (15,5)
       NdE: $(_FrameworkVersionForImplicitDefine)="2_1" (vorheriger Wert: "2.1") unter TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (157,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP7" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP6") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets (38,9)
       NdE: $(_DebugSymbolsProduced)="true" (vorheriger Wert: "false") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (152,5)
       NdE: $(_DocumentationFileProduced)="false" (vorheriger Wert: "true") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (157,5)
       NdE: $(ProcessorArchitecture)="amd64" (vorheriger Wert: "x64") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (473,5)
       NdE: $(DelaySign)="" (vorheriger Wert: "false") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (525,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP8" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP7") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (536,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP9" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP8") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (537,5)
       NdE: $(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)="Auto" (vorheriger Wert: "") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3496,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP10" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP9") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\NuGet.targets (45,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP11" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP10") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.targets (14,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP12" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP11") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.targets (15,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP13" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP12") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets (16,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP14" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP13") unter DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.TestPlatform.targets (17,5)
       NdE: $(MSB)=";PROPS5_TP15" (vorheriger Wert: ";PROPS5_TP14") unter PROJECT_PATH\obj\my_project.csproj.nuget.g.targets (4,5)
       NdE: $(FilePreview)="false" (vorheriger Wert: "") unter C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webjobs.publish\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.targets (36,5)
     1>Projekt "PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj" auf Knoten "1", Restore Ziel(e).
     1>Erstellung mit der Toolsversion "15.0".
     1>C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webjobs.publish\2.0.0\build\webjobs.console.targets(24,3): error MSB4019: Das importierte Projekt "DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" wurde nicht gefunden. Vergewissern Sie sich, dass der Pfad in der <Import>-Deklaration korrekt und die Datei auf dem Datenträger vorhanden ist. [PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj]
     1>Die Erstellung des Projekts "PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj" ist abgeschlossen, Restore Ziel(e) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

       "PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj" (Restore Ziel) (1) ->
         C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webjobs.publish\2.0.0\build\webjobs.console.targets(24,3): error MSB4019: Das importierte Projekt "DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" wurde nicht gefunden. Vergewissern Sie sich, dass der Pfad in der <Import>-Deklaration korrekt und die Datei auf dem Datenträger vorhanden ist. [PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    1 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.52
```

To add the verbose output I had to shorten it by replacing repetitive values with placeholders:

```
NdE: Neuzuweisung der Eigenschaft
MSB: MsBuildAllProjects
DOTNET_SDK_PATH: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
TARGETS_PATH: DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets
SDK_TARGETS_PATH: DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets
PROPS: DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props
PROPS1: PROPS;NUGET.G.PROPS
PROPS2: PROPS1;NET.SDK.PROPS
PROPS3: PROPS2;NET.SDK.DEFAULT.PROPS
PROPS4: PROPS3;NET.SupTarFrameW.PROPS
PROPS5: PROPS4;NET.SDK.C#.PROPS
PROPS5_TP: PROPS5;SDK_TARGETS_PATH
PROPS5_TP1: PROPS5_TP;TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets
PROPS5_TP2: PROPS5_TP1;ms.net.defaultAssemblyInfo.targets
PROPS5_TP3: PROPS5_TP2;TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.DefaultOutputPaths.targets
PROPS5_TP4: PROPS5_TP3;TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets
PROPS5_TP5: PROPS5_TP4;TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets
PROPS5_TP6: PROPS5_TP5;TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.NuGetOfflineCache.targets
PROPS5_TP7: PROPS5_TP6;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets
PROPS5_TP8: PROPS5_TP7;PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
PROPS5_TP9: PROPS5_TP8;PROJECT_PATH\my_project.csproj.user
PROPS5_TP10: PROPS5_TP9;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\NuGet.targets
PROPS5_TP11: PROPS5_TP10;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.targets
PROPS5_TP12: PROPS5_TP11;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.targets
PROPS5_TP13: PROPS5_TP12;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets
PROPS5_TP14: PROPS5_TP13;DOTNET_SDK_PATH\2.1.300\Microsoft.TestPlatform.targets
PROPS5_TP15: PROPS5_TP14;PROJECT_PATH\obj\my_project.csproj.nuget.g.targets

NUGET.G.PROPS: PROJECT_PATH\obj\my_project.csproj.nuget.g.props
NET.SDK.PROPS: TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props
NET.SDK.DEFAULT.PROPS: TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.props
NET.SupTarFrameW.PROPS: TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.SupportedTargetFrameworks.props
NET.SDK.C#.PROPS: NET.SDK.C#.PROPS
ms.net.defaultAssemblyInfo.targets : TARGETS_PATH\Microsoft.NET.DefaultAssemblyInfo.targets
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the log verbosity? (add either `-v d` for detailed logging, or `-v diag` for diagnostic logging)

Comment: Also, the [description for that package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish) states that it is "is used to help support deployment of Azure WebJobs from within Microsoft Visual Studio" so it's probably added in by VS.

Comment: I added the project file and verbose output.

Comment: I'm not deploying to Azure at the moment, but to a Ubuntu 16.04 server.  Not sure what you mean by your last comment.

Comment: You have a reference `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" Version="2.0.0" />` in your project file - I'd remove it if you're not using it at the moment.

Comment: I see,ok. thanks. I managed to resolve the issue and posted an answer, although not sure what exactly did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things I found when googling the problem, I eventually managed to solve it.  However, I'm not exactly sure what solved it because I did several things that didn't work on their own until I updated the Windows Powershell from within Visual Studio.

1. I run the WebJobs.Publish installer: `Install-Package Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish -Version 2.0.0`
2. I copied the contents of v14.0 folder under C:Programme(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio to a v15.0 folder
3. I added Import Sections in my Project File, didn't work, removed them again
4. Installed MSBuildTools which was supposed to install missing libraries, but it still didn't work after that.
5. I applied the latest Patch of Visual Studio - still not working
6. Noticed an Update for PowerShell within Visual Studio Notifications and selected this together with Data Lake and SQLServer update. After I closed Visual Studio it started the update and after it finished I tried again, and this time it appears to be working again.

There were various other things I tried but one of these did the trick.